# Where is my script?

Tags: scripting, saving

I started using Blender recently. I wrote a very nice and long script doing an animation in the text editor. I saved my project. When I reopened my project, I couldn't find my script! Where did it go?

Comment: See the answer below. You should have your text stored in your saved .blend-file, it is in the dropdown list. If it isn't there, maybe you unselected the blue shield icon (fake user) that makes sure to keep the text file stored in .blend-file. This is a really strange concept Blender uses in other parts too. In that case you may have lost your code, unless you saved it out as a text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't save it in a separate file, try searching in the datablock selector:

[image]